# live plotting by using xgraph

Tags: linux, graph, plot

I've been using xgraph due to its simplicity. What I normally do is

```
echo -e "0 0\n1 1\n2 2\n4 4" | xgraph
```

which is just piping to xgraph with 2-column data.  I'm now craving for live plotting by using xgraph such as

```
tail -f data | xgraph
```

In other shell, I'm feeding to data

```
echo "5 6" > data
```

But, sadly, xgraph looks like not supporting such command "tail -f data | xgraph"

Is there any trick or better way for this?